JNDI Datasource with Genexus
There was a time when the recommended way to connect a Genexus web application to a database was using a JNDI Datasource. If remember correctly, it was because it mananged the pool better than the Genexus implementation.
What´s the best practice now? Are you using JDNI Datasources on production with Genexus?
